# Reduce with condition in array js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, filter, reduce

i'm facing a problem with filter and reduce.
I need to get the sum of "smc" only when "A" is equal 2020.
This is my array:

```
arr = [{A:2020, smc:1},{A:2020, smc:2}, {A:2021, smc:3}]
```

I've tried something like:

```
arr.filter(e=> e.A===2020).reduce((sum, iter) => sum + iter.smc)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas why?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass second argument as `0` to `reduce()` which becomes the initial value of `sum`.

```
arr.filter(e=> e.A===2020).reduce((sum, iter) => sum + iter.smc, 0)
```

You can also remove `filter()` use `reduce()` only with ternary operator

```js
const arr = [{A:2020, smc:1},{A:2020, smc:2}, {A:2021, smc:3}];
let res = arr.reduce((ac, {smc, A}) => ac + (A === 2020 ? smc : 0), 0);
console.log(res)
```